MyDAC fetches data despite FetchAll := False
I would like my dataset to not fetch the data as soon as it is opened. I set FetchAll := False but I can see in the MySQL server logs that it still does a SELECT *. How can I actually stop it from doing so ?
Note that setting Limit := 0 does not stop it either. It just executes the request with LIMIT 0...

Fetchall=FALSE probably just stops it from sending the results across the wire, it probably is intended to open a cursor on the server, which is what select * does.
select * on the server as a way to get a cursor is not expensive.
If you ever need to read data in this dataset, you need to not have the limit set to 0, as that will make the cursor non functional. Unclear what you actually want to accomplish as what ever you think you're doing you're probably just making the dataset non functional.
try using a query with an insert statement and params instead of a dataset

Unfortunately, I cannot use a query as I need the MyDAC encryption to be applied, and this is available only on datasets.

What?  What encryption does MyDAC do?   I think whatever you think is going on isn’t. MyDac plus what database?  The transport layer encryption is not a feature of aDAC.  A DAC is a wrapper between delphi data sets and queries and a native DB’s driver DLLs

Indeed, the dataset in MyDAC is a descendant of TDataSet and functions according to the "lifecycle" of TDataSet. It is expected that when the Open() method is called, the dataset retrieves data. At this moment, the .Bof and .Eof properties are initialized, and access to the first record of the retrieved record set becomes available through the Fields classes, etc. All descendants of TDataSet behave similarly.
Altering this behavior can lead to ambiguous situations. We provide certain properties to control the number of records loaded into the dataset upon opening. You can set FetchAll = False and FetchRows = 1. In this case, when the Open() method is called, only a single record will be loaded into the dataset, minimizing traffic between the application and the server during dataset initialization.
